# Excel import to share point not working

Tags: sharepoint-2010

Anyone know how to import data using excel to already created employees profile's list.
As there is only export to excel option available, and after i done some modifications in that same excel file and tried to import to sharepoint web portal it's not happening, it's say's connection time out.But if i refresh the data the value is taking from live share point.and there is no connection error happening.
 Can anyone knows is any other way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: What actually are you doing? Updating UserProfile information?

Comment: @ben: yes i want to update user profile, as there is already some list of employees i want to update their information using Excel. Can i able to do with excel.

Comment: I would use powershell to read it as csv see http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/13547.updating-user-profile-properties-with-powershell-in-sharepoint-2010.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I would convert it to CSV or import it into Sharepoint here is a good example of updating user information in user profiles

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/13547.updating-user-profile-properties-with-powershell-in-sharepoint-2010.aspx

Comment: thanks for the valuable information and the link which you shared.I also would like to know where to write these scripts and how to execute it?if you don't mind can you give an example?

Comment: You would need access to the server, where sharepoint powershell copnsole is available. Powershell scripts can be just written in notepad, with .ps1 extension. Start small eg just connecting to sharepoint and open a web in powershell. Its a very useful skill to have